# AngularJS arhitecture

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

I have the following app where I loop through some data and display it.

```
<div class="thing" ng-repeat="thing in things">
          <h1>{{thing.title}}</h1>
          <p>{{thing.description}}</p>
          <br/>
          <div class="child">
              <!-- ng-repeat="child in ??? -->
              <p>Display child here</p>
          </div>

      </div>
```

My data:

```
$scope.things = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'First thing',
    description: 'This is just a thing',
    extra: {
        childs: 3 /* the id of the children */
    }
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Second thing',
    description: 'This is just a thing',
    extra: {}
}, { /* dont displat this object in the ng-repeat="thing in things" */
    id: 3,
    title: 'Child thing',
    description: 'This is a child thing',
    extra: {}
}]
```

What I dont understand its how to `ng-repeat` just the **THINGS that are NOT CHILDREN** and in the `.child` div to display the element with the id of `thing.extra.childs`.

Can someone explain me how to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18350/

Comment: Ok I got the question it is looking for first element child = 3 is referring to the JSON object with id=3 and you dont want to repeat that. Can you improve your JSON ?

Comment: I agree with @joyBlanks, you should try to improve your JSON data structure, that would make things much easier.

Comment: Any suggestions? The data comes from an rest API, I can add child: { all the data from id:3 } but I'm using an API

Comment: I guess when you receive the data iterate and get the child object moved into the extra key. ie resolve the reference. Anyhow angular will iterate but it will iterate smoothly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to morph the data object for sure. You also dont want the child to be displayed in the list. Basically iterate and get the child object moved into the extra key. ie resolve the reference

** You dont want complex logic to be handled in displays, so in your model you should be doing all dirty work. Since you cant change the API we will change the API references

In your controller, I guess this will be coming from API say you have the JSON in variable `data`.

```
//data will be coming from API
/*data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'First thing',
    description: 'This is just a thing',
    extra: {
        childs: 3 
    }
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Second thing',
    description: 'This is just a thing',
    extra: {}
}, { 
    id: 3,
    title: 'Child thing',
    description: 'This is a child thing',
    extra: {}
}]; */
```

Then you can morph this JSON right below you receive your data put this code in your controller.

```
for(var i in data){
  if(data[i].extra && data[i].extra.childs){
    for(var j in data){
      if(data[j].id == data[i].extra.childs){
        data[i].child = data[j];
        delete(data[j]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

$scope.things = data;//then put the morphed JSON in the $scope.things
```

The HTML will be like this. Note I have added a key `child` in your JSON who had children

```
<div class="thing" ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <h1>{{thing.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{thing.description}}</p>
    <br/>
    <div class="child" ng-if="things.child">
        <p>{{thing.child.title}}</p>
        <p>{{thing.child.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="thing" ng-repeat="thing in things">
        <h1>{{thing.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{thing.description}}</p>
        <br/>
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in thing.extra" class="child">
            <p>{{ key }} : {{ value }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want the object, I know to displat the ID

Comment: which object? I don't get it

Comment: you would like to display the key-value pair in the html?

Comment: Yep, and in thing in things dont displat the things that are childs

Comment: I've just updated the snippet with an ng-repeat with key-value pairs. is it this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-if directive for that purpose :

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

      <div ng-repeat="thing in things">
          <h1>{{thing.title}}</h1>
          <p>{{thing.description}}</p>
          <p ng-if="thing.extra.childs">
              {{thing.extra.childs}}
          </p>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/op4j7jhj/

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants, check the comments under the question.

Comment: Exactly, I want the object, I know to displat the ID